# How can I set a variable to be the same across all created objects of the same type?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class I made called `Car`. In that class there is methods and other variables. I have a variable called `make` though that needs to always be the same across all `Car` objects. The only problem is I want to know what make will be before a `Car` object has been initialized. I tried using static but I must have a misconception of how static methods and static variables function. I tried calling a static method which sets the static variable but when I create a `Car` object it did not work.

example: `Car.setMake("Toyota")`

Where the static method `setMake()` sets the static variable `make`.
Then I would create a `new Car()` and expect all `Car` objects to be of the `make` "Toyota". This does not work.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the code on how you are using static

Comment: Seems like it would make more sense to instantiate a factory.

Comment: @OldProgrammer no, oleg figured it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about `static` variables. Check it again. `Static` variables and mothods bolong to the `Class` itselfe and all instances of `Class` have the same values.
`Static` methods have access to `static` variables and methods only, but `non-static` methods have access to `static` and `non-static` variables and methods.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Car audi = new Car();
    Car bmw = new Car();
    System.out.println(Car.getMake());  // null
    Car.setMake("Toyota");
    System.out.println(Car.getMake());  // Toyota
    System.out.println(audi.getMake()); // Toyota
    System.out.println(bmw.getMake());  // Toyota
}

class Car {

    private static String make;

    public static void setMake(String make) {
        Car.make = make;
    }

    public static String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah I see I was calling the static method before instantiating the ```Car``` object!

Comment: @ErlichBachman this is does not matter. You can write and read `static` variables even before first instance of class.